# How to decide on number of units in RNN Keras layer?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am new to RNN and trying to understand them. My question is: Is the number of neurons dependent on the size of the sequence and the number of time steps? My main understanding is since it takes a sequence of input then the number of neurons should be the same as the size of the sequence. if we have 10 time-steps and thus 10 different inputs then, we should have 10 neurons. If no then how do we feed or sequence to the neurons if we have a sequence of size 20 and 10 neurons only?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you reconsider your question. Whenever you have an issue and want some help, you should look at look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, in order to formulate a "quality question". Basically, you need to be more specific: there are a lot of questions in your post. Please leave only one specific question

Comment: You already asked this question before, questions can only be asked once. This is not a forum. You can always edit your original question. And more importantly, I already answered this in comments in your other question!

Answer (score 0):

I will answer your first question.

Generally - yes, the number of neurons is dependent on the size of the sequence: the more neurons - the better prediction of longer sequences. But even one neuron may give you a perfect prediction if your sequence is simple (e.g. if your sequence is [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]).